# How to add multiple nodes to relations

Tags: clojure, neo4j, cypher

How to add multiple node to relations here is my query
 `MATCH (n:Customer{name:"motoM"})-[:RECENT {default:TRUE}]-(l:Location{name:"Adugodi"}) return l` how to write a query to add one more "location" node to the relation "recent" if location node is not found and setting default to true to newly created realtion

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
MATCH (n:Customer{name:"motoM"})-[:RECENT {default:TRUE}]-(l:Location{name:"Adugodi"})
MERGE (n)-[:RECENT]->(l2:Location)
ON CREATE SET l2.default = true
RETURN l, l2
```

The direction needs to be specified so I made it up, but it might need to go the other way.

Comment: Also, if the `l2` is actually a location which you want to create a relationship to you should add it to your `MATCH` to limit it (by `name` for instance) instead and do `(n)-[:RECENT]->(l2)` for the merge.

Comment: Hi brain
"MATCH (n:Customer{name:"motoM"})-[:RECENT {default:TRUE}]->(l:Location{name:"Adugodi"})"
ON merge its creating a new node for customer but it should not create new nodes for customer

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if I understood what you were looking for, but this might help you :)

Try with this query:

```
MATCH (n:Customer{name:"motoM"})-[r:RECENT {default:TRUE}]-(:Location{name:"Adugodi"}) 

CREATE (l2:Location{name:"Wherever You need"})

With r,n,l,l2

Set r.default = false

With n,l2

CREATE (n)-[r2:RECENT{default:TRUE}]->(l2)
```

I'm using `With`to make the query easier to read, but you can do it in a single query.

In fact, I think your problem is your Graph model.

You should probably do something like a Customer node, related to Location nodes with a "VISITED" relation, and when you create your VISITED relation, you set date property to timestamp. Then, when you get your relations, you can simply compare timestamps to get the closest one, and you know which one is the one your need. Also, if you need a default property, set it on the node, it'll be easier to match.

Tell me if you need a code example for match, create and set data with this graph model.